# Fourier transform on image Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, fft

I'm having problems to get the correct fourier trasform of an image.
I have an MRI image of the brain and I have to compute the FT of it. I should get something like a big white cross in the center but instead I get this, which is similar to white noise.

[image]

This is the code.

```
brain = imread('brain.jpeg');
brain_bw = rgb2gray(brain);
brain_DFT = fft2(brain_bw);
brain_DFT_shifted = fftshift(brain_DFT);

figure;
subplot(1,2,1);
    imshow(brain);
    title('Original Image');
subplot(1,2,2);
    imshow(brain_DFT_shifted);
    title('Fourier Trasform');
```

In fact I also tried to compute the inverse fourier trasnform but I get another white noise.

```
inverse = ifft2(brain_DFT_shifted);
    figure(); imshow(inverse);
```

[image]

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: I may have solved it by using `mat2gray(log(1+abs(brain_DFT_shifted)))` but I am open to other solutions

Comment: This is a display issue. The Fourier transform has complex values, and a large dynamic range. Using a logarithmic mapping of the magnitude is appropriate (for display only, keep the original complex values to inverse transform). For the inverse transform, you need to shift back first (`ifftshift`).